# Trying to run MATLAB through an ssh connection, MATLAB process hangs

Tags: windows-7, ssh, cygwin, matlab

I have two computers and I am attempting to ssh from one to the other and then running an automated MATLAB script. My sshd and ssh client are both from OpenSSH via Cygwin on both machines, which are running Windows 7 64-bit.

I ssh and then run MATLAB:

```
root@Worker1 ~
$ ssh WORKER3
Last login: Mon Feb 13 14:44:48 2012 from worker1

root@Worker3 ~
$ matlab
```

and I have the PATH set so that the 64-bit version of MATLAB runs. Then when I look at the Windows Task Manager on Worker3, I see that there is a MATLAB.exe process that is taking up about 14 MB of RAM, when typically MATLAB takes up much more RAM than that. Nothing else happens (including if I launch MATLAB with instructions to run a script using /r).  So it seems that MATLAB is not finishing starting up. Running MATLAB with arguments such as /nodesktop /nosplash /minimize etc. does the same thing. What might cause this problem? I have a setup that is identical as far as I can tell on another computer and it runs fine, but clearly it is not as identical as I think.

Comment: Is your remote machine Windows (32bit or 64bit) or OSX (x86 or PPC) or Linux (32bit or 64bit)?

Comment: Both machines are Windows 7 64 bit Enterprise edition

Comment: Use psexec.exe fom pstools available on http://www.sysinternals.com
No need to go ways around with SSH